# Jenkins unable to connect to remote ip address

Tags: jenkins

Can someone tell me how to allow Jenkins to connect to another IP address as i getting below error? I tried `telnet` from Jenkins but it did not work.

```
fatal: [152.32.97.23]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Data could not
 be sent to remote host \"152.32.97.23\". Make sure this host can be reached over 
ssh: ssh: connect to host 152.32.97.23 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", 
"unreachable": true}
```

Comment: You need to open inbound port 22 on the instance whose IP is 152.32.97.23

Comment: If you have been able to resolve your issue, it's good to post your solution as an answer so others could benefit from it. :)

Comment: hi i haven't test it. waiting for approval on the suggested solution. once fix will post it as answer.